# Changing resolution in Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, display-resolution

I'm new to Linux. I've tried a lot of different ways, but all effort failed - usually because they pertain to Ubuntu desktop, rather than server, and because they rely on packages being present which aren't, or a graphical interface.

I'm running 12.04 - fresh install in a VM

I've tried editing `/etc/default/grub` followed by `update-grub` and `reboot` - this either achieves nothing, or results in a failure to reboot.

I try to run `vbeinfo` and it says *unknown command*.

How can I increase the size of the console window?

I've tried using `xrandr` which required a package install of `x11-server-utils`, but after installation all I got when I typed `xrandr` was *Can't open display*

Some people have said about "grub menu"... what is it? If I type grub, it tells me to install a package. I do so, and type grub and I get the grub console. Is this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can add kernel parameter vga=792 (depends on your monitor) in `/etc/default/grub`

```
  VGA Resolution Codes for GRUB & Lilo
--- Depth --
Colors  bits  640x480  800×600  1024×768  1152×864 1280×1024  1600×1200
   256    8   vga=769  vga=771   vga=773   vga=353   vga=775    vga=796
 32000    ?   vga=784  vga=787   vga=790   vga= ?    vga=793    vga= ? 
 65000   16   vga=785  vga=788   vga=791   vga=355   vga=794    vga=798
 16.7M   24   vga=786  vga=789   vga=792   vga=795   vga=799
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

You will be able to choose from a variety of fonts and font sizes for the console.