# Ubuntu 14 Text mode

Tags: 14.04

[image]I am running ubuntu in text mode but it only fills 1/4 of my screen depending on what i choose in console-setup. I have changed grub to fit my needs but only the resolution changes, not the text size nor window. I have tried almost everything but can't seem to run our program in fulscreen mode. It is possible cause we are running it fullscreen on centos. any Ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed an ubuntu-server 14.04 edition? Is that what you mean by "text mode"?
If that's so, I will recommend you to see the following links:

[Proper way to change terminal resolution in Ubuntu Server 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299975/proper-way-to-change-terminal-resolution-in-ubuntu-server-13-04)

[Maximum terminal resolution in ubuntu server virtual box guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456527/maximum-terminal-resolution-in-ubuntu-server-virtual-box-guest)

[Changing resolution in Ubuntu Server 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347497/changing-resolution-in-ubuntu-server-12-04)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS is installed. Like i said, I have edited my grub to my screen resolution, the screen gets bigger but the console is still small, it does not auto adjust to my screen size, text is small as well. There is no GUI i disabled it, it is only text mode/console

Comment: And I tried all the links

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. If the screen gets bigger and text is smaller then you actually changed your screen resolution. Probably because you entered a different resolution that is not supported by your monitor is that you are getting a non desired result. The system without GUI can only support one definition. So, the screen will get smaller and the fonts bigger or vice-versa. What are the supported resolutions for your monitor? Exactly what you edited on the grub?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot, maybe now you will understand

Comment: so, when you make the changes the blue square changes the sizes right? making the font smaller. And your problem is that you want the blue square as if it is a fullscreen app?

Comment: When I make the changes the bluescreen stays the same size but my screen's resolution gets bigger, so when I make it 1440x900 for instance, the resolution changes but the blue screen stays same size, it does not fill everything. The fonts sizes does not change no matter what the resolution.